# GWT Deferred Binding and Dependency Injection

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection

Assuming I have something like so

Interface

```
Interface IsInterface {}
```

Implementation Classes

```
public ConcreteClassA implements IsInterface {

 InjectorA a, InjectorB c, InjectorC c;

 @Inject
 ConcreteClassA(InjectorA a, InjectorB b, InjectorC c) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   .....
 }

}

public ConcreteClassB implements IsInterface {

 InjectorA a, InjectorB B, InjectorC C;

 @Inject
 ConcreteClassB(InjectorA a, InjectorB b, InjectorC c) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   .....
 }

}
```

..and then I decide to use GWT deferred binding so in my GWT module.gwt.xml

```
//Pseudo XML Configuration
if (type is IsInterface) 
   if toggle == A then use ConcreteClass A else use ConcreteClassB
```

Now, when I try to run this. It won't work because GWT expected my Concrete Class A and B to have default 0 constructor. So, I tried the following on my concrete class

```
 @Inject
 InjectorA a; 
 @Inject
 InjectorB b;
 @Inject
 InjectorC c;

 ConcreteClassA() {

 }
```

which bypass the 0 constructor error but it gives me NullPointerException when I try to use a, b or c. One way to make it to work is to remove @Inject and use GWT.create() like so

```
 InjectorA a, InjectorB b, InjectorC c;

 ConcreteClassA() {
   this.a = GWT.create(InjectorA.class);
   .....
   .....
 }
```

This will work but what if my InjectorA, InjectorB and InjectorC have none 0 constructor and depended heavily on @inject. I dont want to go through all the classes to create 0 constructors and replace @inject with GWT.create(). There has to be a better way to do this. Am I missing something here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gin Injection Inside Class Generated By Deferred Binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490729/gin-injection-inside-class-generated-by-deferred-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this

```
interface IsInterface {
 @Inject
 void init(InjectorA a, InjectorB b, ...);
}

public ConcreteClassA implements IsInterface {

 InjectorA a, InjectorB c, InjectorC c;
 ConcreteClassA() {}
 @Override
 public void init(InjectorA a, InjectorB b, ..) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  ....
 }

}
```